# CURL Post form with captcha not work

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I have write a curl function use to get captcha from a website, then display on my site. User will input value and captcha and submit.
I will get value summit from user and re post to website to get data info.
Before I code in one file it work. But now i split it to three file just copy code but now it doesn't work.

Please help me.
My code curl function

```
private function makeCurl($url, $data = null) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
        $headers[] = '_eosAjax: xml';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->myCookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->myCookie);      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

        if($data != null) {
            $data_string = "";
            foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $data_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($data_string, '&');
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        }
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

draw captcha function

```
public function drawCatcha() {
        $result = $this->makeCurl(HOST."zdxt/gjyjqcgzcx/gjyjqcgzcx_drawValidCode.action");  
        $ImageCaptcha=base64_encode($result);

        return "data:image/jpeg;base64,".$ImageCaptcha;
    }
```

check captcha function

```
private function checkCaptcha($code) {
        $data = array(
            "submitType"=>1,
            "ajax"=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root><params><param><key>validcode</key><value>{$code}</value></param></params><data></data></root>"
        );

        $result = $this->makeCurl(HOST."zdxt/gjyjqcgzcx/gjyjqcgzcx_validCode.action", $data);

        return $result;
    }
```

And get info function

```
public function getInfo($code, $port) {
        echo $this->checkCaptcha($code);
        $data = array(
            "submitType" => 2,
            "ajax" => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root><params><param><key>vYjhm</key><value>RM649904215CN</value></param><param><key>vYjhmLst</key><value>'RM649904215CN'</value></param><param><key>validcode</key><value>{$code}</value></param></params> <data><criteria><_entity></_entity></criteria><page><begin>0</begin><length>100</length><count>-1</count><isCount>true</isCount></page></data></root>"
        );
        $result = $this->makeCurl(HOST."zdxt/gjyjqcgzcx/gjyjqcgzcx_gjyjqcgzcxDqztQueryPage.action", $data);
        $info = simplexml_load_string($result);
        return $info;

    }
```

I have three file now. Post.php with all function work with curl.
input.php display the form and call draw captcha. and result.php call to get info
And there is the website I want to get info 
http://intmail.183.com.cn/zdxt/jsp/zhdd/gjyjgzcx/gjyjqcgzcx/gjyjqcgzcx.jsp

Comment: you splitted the code into three files but did you included the files properly in the file where you are calling the functions????

Comment: Yes, Sure. If not I will display error message can't not create new Post class.

Comment: Is `$this->myCookie` the same file across each request and can you confirm the cookies are being saved successfully?

Comment: Yes, Because file name is ID of user session. And when I confirm cookie file has save successfully.